# ¿Cómo imprimir dos columnas en una variable?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy usando este array para imprimir dos campos, pero no imprime la variable.

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT nombre AND tel FROM tel LIMIT 20 " ,$con);            
    $contar = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if($contar == 0){

    }else{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $column = array($row['tel'] );
    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
       $arrlength = count($column[$x]);

?> 
<option value='<?php echo $column[$x]; ?>' required > <?php echo $column[$x] ; ?>  </option>            
<?php 

    }}
}

?>
```

Comment: que es lo que te imprime???

Comment: Una consideración a tomar en cuenta es que la extensión ´mysql´ fue **declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0.** además por sus múltiples aspectos de seguridad en su aplicación debería dejar de usar dicha extensión.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba:

```
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT concat(nombre,' ',tel) as nom_tel from tel LIMIT 20 " ,$con);
    $contar = mysql_num_rows($sql);

            if($contar != 0)
            {

              while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

              echo $column = array($row['nom_tel'] ); #echo en pruebas

            }   
?> 
    <option value='<?= $column; ?>' required > <?= $column ; ?></option>
```

Espero haberte servido de ayuda